# How to check status of checkbox in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have a scenario to verify the status of checkbox whether this is disable or enable but i did not fine any keyword for that, It would be great if somebody help to get this.

Comment: We will require more information about this? What exactly are you trying to do? What have u done so far in it and what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "[Checkbox Should Be Selected](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Checkbox%20Should%20Be%20Selected)" and "[Checkbox Should Not Be Selected](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Checkbox%20Should%20Not%20Be%20Selected)" keywords for that.

If you don't expect a specific value (selected/not selected), then use the "[Run Keyword and return status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status)" which "two values, so that the first is either 'PASS' or 'FAIL', depending on the status of the executed keyword"